# Is there any plan to introduce a hierarchical tag model to accommodate version-specific tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-synonyms, tag-search

When I visit stackoverflow.com I'm mostly interested in Python-related questions, so naturally [`python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is the first tag I search for, but then I feel compelled to also check out [`python-2.7`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), [`python-3.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), and [`python-3.6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6) just so that I don't miss any topics that are only tagged with python of a specific version, but are still clearly related to Python in general.

These are three unnecessary extra page clicks I have to go through every time I visit the site just because I'm interested in Python. I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one who's bothered by having to do this, and it leaves questions tagged with just a version-specific Python under-exposed.

Is there any plan to introduce a hierarchical tag model such that it allows either:

1. Searching for a broader term automatically searches for more specific terms, e.g. searching for the tag `python-3.x` automatically includes topics tagged with `python-3.6`, and searching for `python` automatically includes topics tagged with `python-2.7` and `python-3.x` (and therefore, hierarchically, `python-3.6`), or,
2. Tagging a more specific term automatically tags broader terms, e.g. when a user tags a question with `python-3.6`, the site automatically also adds tags `python-3.x` and therefore `python` to the question?

Please note that this differs from tag synonyms because what's needed here is a hierarchical relationship between tags, not equivalency. So in option 1, searching for `python-3.x` also searches for `python-3.6`, but does not search for `python`, and in option 2, tagging a question with `python-3.x` also tags `python`, but doesn't automatically tag `python-3.6`.

Thanks for your considerations.

Comment: You know you can search for [`python-3*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3*%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)?

Comment: @rene Thanks that works. Did not find the help page on search syntax until now. Should've searched harder.

Comment: @rene You can even search for [`python*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython*%5D+is%3Aq), which returns any tag that starts with `python`, including [python] itself.

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223400/can-we-group-constrain-and-add-heirarchy-to-tags

Comment: @DonaldDuck IIRC those python devs are pretty serious if it is a 2.X or 3.x version. I want to make sure to show they can still search for their favorite python version ;)